# hide url bar on ipad

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, html

After a deep search, I still can't hide the URL bar in my IPAD web app.

please help

I tried to add:

`meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes"`

meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"

But it works only if I add the site to my home screen...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suggested fix for this I've come across is scrolling the web page down to hide the URL bar. This can be achieved with Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});
```

[Source article](http://davidwalsh.name/hide-address-bar)